# Python For loop on Dict with multiple Values per Key

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark

I want to create a Dict with 2 Values per each Key. I don't know whether it's better to make the Values for each Key a List, or another Dictionary.
But, ultimately I want to loop through each Key once only, and then within the loop of each key, loop through the 2 elements in the Value (in sequence).

I have this code:

```
dic = {'%serial_number%':['SERIAL_NUMBER :: (\w+)','number'],'%sw_version%':['SW_VERSION :: HR6400 ([\d\.\-]+)','ver']}
def match_regex(text):
    for k,v in dic.iteritems():
        for v1 in v:
            print(text,k,text,v1[0],v1[1])
match_regex(df.value)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
(Column<value>, '%sw_version%', Column<value>, 'S', 'W')
(Column<value>, '%sw_version%', Column<value>, 'v', 'e')
(Column<value>, '%serial_number%', Column<value>, 'S', 'E')
(Column<value>, '%serial_number%', Column<value>, 'n', 'u')
```

The Output I WOULD LIKE would appear like this:

```
(Column<value>, '%serial_number%', Column<value>, 'SERIAL_NUMBER :: (\w+)', 'number')
(Column<value>, '%sw_version%', Column<value>, 'SW_VERSION :: HR6400 iDirect ([\d\.\-]+)', 'ver')
```

I am using PySpark, but it shouldn't matter, it's Python 2.7. THE FUNCTION needs to be generic, so I only want to reference it by index, NOT by the string content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of a loop to display each items in value.

`v` is simply a list which is the value for the key `k`. `v[0]` is the first item of value and `v[1]` is the second item.

```
dic = {'%serial_number%':['SERIAL_NUMBER :: (\w+)','number'],'%sw_version%':['SW_VERSION :: HR6400 ([\d\.\-]+)','ver']}

def match_regex(text):
    for k, v in dic.iteritems():
        print(text,k,text,v[0],v[1])

match_regex(df.value)

# (Column<value>, '%serial_number%', Column<value>, 'SERIAL_NUMBER :: (\w+)', 'number') 
# (Column<value>, '%sw_version%', Column<value>, 'SW_VERSION :: HR6400 iDirect ([\d\.\-]+)', 'ver')
```